# Solr SuggestComponent - Building dictionaries based on certain filters?

Tags: solr, lucene

I am currently using the solr suggest component for an autocomplete feature. Now, according to user permissions and which area of the site I am on, I want to offer the user different suggestions. Now I assumed it would easily be possible to only consider certain explicit entries for building my dictionary (i.e.: dict1 is built only from entries where type=t1 and locale=en, dict 2 where type=t1 and locale=de, dict3 where type=t2 and locale=en, etc...). But I can't figure out where I would do such a thing. The system is running solr 4.6.

Do you know of any solution or have a possible workaround?

I am not currently able to update solr on the system or change the way documents are indexed apart from the solr configuration, so unfortunately context filtering is not available to me. This would only be a last resort if nothing else works.

Answer (score 0):

Since you’re using old **Solr 4.6** which doesn’t have context filtering or even multiple dictionaries, you would need to specify your dictionaries aka SearchComponent for each of the entry

```
<searchComponent class="solr.SpellCheckComponent" name="suggest-en">
   <lst name="spellchecker">
-->
<!--
<str name="name">suggest</str>
<str name="classname">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.Suggester</str>
<str name="lookupImpl">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.tst.TSTLookup</str>
<str name="field">name</str>  <!-- the indexed field to derive suggestions from
<float name="threshold">0.005</float>
<str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
<str name="sourceLocation">american-english</str>
--> </lst>
</searchComponent>
```

And then define request handlers, like this:

```
<requestHandler class="org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler"
name="/suggest-en">
   <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="spellcheck">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">suggest-en</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.count">5</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
   </lst>
   <arr name="components">
      <str>suggest</str>
   </arr>
</requestHandler>
```

The workaround here would be, that you would need to specify `suggest-en`, `suggest-de`, and all other types of the request handlers, and later point out clients depends on their profile to the correct request handler.